# Altium Designer, no libraries

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I've just got Altium Designer, and while I was searching for some components I discovered that I only have two libraries:

1. MiscellaneousDevices.IntLib
2. MiscellaneousConnectors.IntLib

Is there any way I can add the default libraries to Altium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiscellaneousDevices.IntLib and MiscellaneousConnectors.IntLib *are* the default libraries for Altium. Other libraries you would either need to download independently or, better yet, create your own. I always create my own libraries, you can find my tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kyY25CGJtM

Alternatively you can download non-default libraries from Altium's website:

https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Download+Libraries

and install them yourself. Keep in mind that the above link may include out-of-date components, so use them at your own risk. I don't imagine they would change much though, so you're probably fine.

Comment: Thank you.
I think the new site as I was directed is https://designcontent.live.altium.com .

I think I will need to watch this tutorial for sure.